# Why is a 3 day Yom Tov permissible, but Shabbos and Yom Kippur cannot be on adjacent days?

Tags: shabbat, calendar, yom-kippur, yom-tov

If Rosh Hashana were to fall on Wednesday or Friday, then that would result in Yom Kippur being on Friday or Sunday. The calendar was designed to avoid this happening since the sages deemed having Shabbos and Yom Kippur adjacent would be difficult due to needing to refrain from melachos.

However, in diaspora, we have recently had the first two days of Pesach immediately followed by Shabbos.

How has 3 consecutive days of refraining from melachos ended up in our calendar, when the caveat for Yom Kippur was made to avoid the 2 days? Are these 3 days not equally a problem?

Comment: What's your source that our calendar was designed with that goal per se? (There were other goals -- avoiding Hoshana Rabba on Shabbos or Purim on Shabbos; maybe Yom Kippur next to Shabbos was just a byproduct.)

Comment: BT Sukkah 54b:6 "Therefore, in order to avoid two consecutive days, when there is a severe prohibition against performing labour, we postpone Rosh Hashana"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yom Tov sheni is rabbinic and thus burial is permitted in certain ways. Shabbos and Yom Kippur are biblical and thus burial would be impossible for too long.

Comment: Also you can cook on Yom Tov. With Yom Kippur it would be two days in a row that you cannot cook or prepare food.

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Rosh_Hashanah.20a.10?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en